# adb Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Tags: android, adb

I'm dealing with a pretty major malware issue on an Elite 6.0L+ Sky Device. I'm working with a fellow from the malware bytes forums trying to get it cleaned out. I'm trying to uninstall a few apps through adb via command prompt but it's throwing errors.

```
adb pm shell pm uninstall com.wouzee.hispanopost
```

That command throws the error:

Failure [DELETE_FAIL_INTERNAL_ERROR]

If I try it as

```
    adb pm shell -k --user 0 uninstall com.wouzee.hispanopost
```

Then is throws: Failure [no installed for 0]

I have managed to uninstall other things using these commands but the two things I've been told to remove both throw these same errors when I try to remove them.

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: No it's not, although not from lack of trying. I have been trying to root this device for days and nothing I've attempted has worked unfortunately.

Comment: You can use this command : `adb shell pm list users` that will show you running and current users, usually you'd only see something like : `UserInfo{0:Owner:13}` (`0` denotes user) but if another user was created, then its possible `com.wouzee.hispanopost` was installed under another user - this is worth a check, and could be why the `--user 0` switch failed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I did try that command and it came back with exactly what you said. Unfortunately I still haven't been able to remove the file. I have found another file that has been identified by the malware bytes staff as malware that I also can't remove. Do you by chance have any suggestions on to root this thing? Would i be able to forcefully remove the offending apk files if it were rooted?

Answer (score 18):

I was having the same problem uninstalling with:

```sh
adb shell

pm uninstall <package>
```

This is what worked for me eventually:

```sh
adb shell

pm uninstall --user 0 <package>
```

Comment: OP literally said that --user 0 doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Some Apps are prevented from uninstalling. You can disable them instead. Use following command on adb shell:

```
pm disable-user --user 0 <package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, I uninstall some system apps come up with [DELETE_FAIL_INTERNAL_ERROR] too

1. use `adb shell su` to enter shell mode
2. then using `pm uninstall --user 0 <your-pkg-name>` to uninstall

PS: if only use `adb shell` my situation will generate error too, the `su` is the key to solve problem

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of [Willam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70315155/8075540)?

Comment: @DanielWalker no, his first command not cotain su, i already said in my answer, not contain su not working for me